# Peoplesoft 8.52 menu authorization error

Tags: peoplesoft

With any kind of account besides administrator, we get an authorization error for the drop down menu. (And other pages)

The users do have the PTPT1000 access with WEBLIB_PT_NAV and full access to every iscript within that weblib.

We also performed a security sync and cleared the cache.

Any ideas on what is wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

An Administrator in PeopleSoft does not have any special access other than what has been granted through Security Administration.

I would try visually comparing the two accounts, and if that proves too arduous, then clone the administrator account and incrementally remove roles until you find the one that is granted the required access.

Just to be on the safe side I would delete the app server and browser cache as the first step.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As a quick temporary fix we gave the user all the web libraries full access which obviously worked. I was hoping that someone knew the exact permission list and web library that controlled this. And while we are on the topic, I also need to know the permission list/web library for drag and drop functionality for pagelets. Thank You.